# Image path production reference is not working in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please someone help, spent hours on this and it's driving me mad.

I'm on rails 4, using apache/passenger if that helps. Also I ran: "rake assets:precompile" and restarted apache.

I'm using this in my style sheet:

```
background-image: url(image-path('pretty-background-image.jpg'));
```

In production this is outputted in the css file:

```
background-image: url("/assets/pretty-background-image.jpg");
```

From this ticket and a lot of messing around, I understand something like this **SHOULD** be outputted:

```
background-image: url("/assets/pretty-background-image-8b313354987c309e3cd76eabdb376c1e.jpg");
```

But it's not. I'm having the same issues with fonts when trying to use:

```
asset-url('font-name.eot')
```

All other images within html.erb files are rendering fine (with the extra string of numbers and letters at the end) but nothing inside of my style sheets is working correctly.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like it should be `background-image: image-url("pretty-background-image.jpg");` - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: how are you generating your assets? is the environment set properly?

Comment: @veritas1 - So the link you sent me references files being served by Sprockets, which is not enabled in production. I think you're misreading the manual, sprockets is correct for dev, not for production as it cannot handle a high load. I think the background image should be something like all the other images, eg: background-image: url("/assets/pretty-background-image-8b313354987c309e3cd76eabdb376c1e.jpg");

Comment: @phoet I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I'm using "rake assets:precompile" and have tried editing the environment variables in a few different ways. Here's my current production config: http://pastebin.com/9paYEUvT I've spent at least an hour gradually going through and enabling items one by one, it hasn't seemed to help at all. 2 things to note, 1. Rails is changing the path in the css when it compiles as noted above (just not to the correct path), and 2. All images outside of css are compiled with the correct path and have numbers/letters trailing at the end of the file.

Comment: did you try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` ?

Comment: No I had not, and now it is fixed. You my friend are a genius. Thankyou!!!

Comment: @phoet - since you understand what's going on here, I'll leave this up to you. If you think this question could help others (I'll say this, I was searching the keywords in this message and this would have certainly helped me), then post your answer so I can accept, otherwise I'll delete the question as not to clutter up the site. Also if there are any further edits you want to make to the question to make it more relevant, or want me to make feel free I'd be happy to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails 4 has incompatible changes when it comes to the asset pipeline.

i think that those changes are good, because they remove a lot of magic, that rails did to keep things backward compatible.

one of those points that were really annoying in rails 3 was the way `rake assets:precompile` worked.

it ALWAYS tried to run the task with the production environment. and it ran twice to generate assets with fingerprints and without them.

nowadays you have to pass the environment to the rake task like `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` when you want to generate assets in production.

the new task does not generate any assets without fingerprints. if you want to have those, you need to build some custom stuff (symlinking stuff from manifest.yml within your capistrano task etc) for that.